# How do I find the values for $u$ and $v$ when transforming an integral from $x,y$ coordinates?

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be the parallelogram whose sides are segments of these four lines: $$y=2x,\quad y=2x+4, \quad y=-x+3,\quad y=-x+5$$ Find $$\int\int_{R} (y-2x)^3 dxdy$$

Usually, the transformations are given to you, but in this case, it seems that I have to determine what u and v are myself.

Answer (score 1):

The lines $$ε_1: y=2x \qquad \text{ and } \qquad ε_2: y=2x+4$$ are parallel since they have the same slope$=2$. Now, observe that you can rewrite them in the form 
$$ε_1: \color{blue}{y-2x}=0 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad ε_2: \color{blue}{y-2x}=4$$ From this you can see that a reasonable substitution is $\color{blue}{u}:=\color{blue}{y-2x}$.

The same applies for the other two lines $$ε_3: y=-x+3 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad ε_4: y=-x+5$$ which are also parallel since they have the same slope$=-1$. Now, observe that you can rewrite them in the form 
$$ε_3: \color{blue}{y+x}=3 \qquad \text{ and } \qquad ε_4: \color{blue}{y+x}=5$$ From this you can see that the other reasonable substitution is $\color{blue}{v}:=\color{blue}{y+x}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $u = y - 2x, v = y+x$.

Can you finish it ?

Comment: Could you explain how you got that? I know how to finish the problem from there. I'm having trouble arriving to what you have written.

Comment: Do you mean y+x is 3 and 5? 
So am I just trying to find a configuration of x and y such that it equals a constant? I'm a little confused as to what u and v actually represent. Why is it that u=y-2x and v=y+x? Could i switch the values of u and v so v=y-2x and u=y+x?

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. Okay, so If im seeing this right, I can switch the values and either make u=y+x and v=y-2x or v=y+x and u=y-2x? I just have use appropriate lines (horizontal or vertical) depending on which one i use?